# how to create a list in python from an existing list with all the elements from first list but with lesser indexes

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example `['ram', 'shyam', 'great', 'bad']` here are four indexes, now I want all the things in list with less indexes like `['ram', 'shyam', 'great,bad']` here only 3 indexes.

Comment: Do you mean `','.join(list)`? What have you tried?

Comment: so you wanna merge them all ?

Answer (score 1):

```
(' '.join(example_list).split(','))
```

where example_list is your list name, you'll edit as u want

an example(you can change range as u want, but shall be lower or equal than len(list)-1 :

```
rangee=2
example_list = ['A','b','C','d']
x = (' '.join(example_list[rangee:]).split(','))
example_list = example_list[:rangee]+x
print(example_list)
```

Comment: This will output `['ram shyam great bad']` here, not the desired outcome.

Comment: well, this is the real code dude, you can modify by changing ' ' to ',' if u want commas between them and just select range like they 've written at top like example_list[range] . I just didn't want to mention since others ve written that

Answer (score 1):

You can do so:

```
a = ['ram', 'shyam', 'great', 'bad']
a[2:4] = [', '.join(a[2:4])]
```

Output:

```
['ram', 'shyam', 'great, bad']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **`join`** and slicing:

```
n = 3
arr[:n-1] + [','.join(arr[n-1:])]
```

Output:

```
['ram', 'shyam', 'great,bad']
```

Replace `n` with however many elements you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can asign the index range, paying attention that `my_list[i:j]` will do from `i th` to `j-1` :

```
my_list = ['ram', 'shyam', 'great', 'bad']
my_list[2:4] = [','.join(my_list[2:4])]
```

output :

```
my_list
['ram', 'shyam', 'great,bad']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use negative index to specify the end of the list so you don't have to know in advance how many items there are in the list:

```
l = ['ram', 'shyam', 'great', 'bad']
print(l[:-2] + [','.join(l[-2:])])
```

This outputs:

```
['ram', 'shyam', 'great,bad']
```